# Byte pair encoding when most bytes are already used

Tags: text, nlp, compression, tokenize

Byte pair encoding is apparently sometimes used to compress/tokenize text prior to running machine learning algorithms on it.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_pair_encoding the basic step is one in which

> the most common pair of contiguous bytes of data in a sequence are replaced with a byte that does not occur within the sequence

I can see how this works for ASCII, which typically leaves about 160 possible bytes unused.

It would seem to be inapplicable for binary data, which in general would use all the possible byte values.

What about Unicode? That uses a lot more of the possible byte values than ASCII. Does the algorithm work less well here, does Unicode use fewer byte values than I am taking into account, or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: You're still likely to have a bunch of unused codes at the beginning (0-31, other than CR, LF and TAB won't likely be used). C0 and C1 are unlikely to be used (redundant coding of single byte chars). F5-FD code points past `U+10FFFF` and 5-6 byte sequences which are not valid AFAIK. FE and FF have no meaning in UTF-8. That's a fair number of potentially usable symbols already. | You could also introduce an escape sequence, and "liberate" some more rarely used codes by escaping them when beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify how the Unicode is encoded. Since you're talking about bytes and ASCII, I will answer for the most common and accepted encoding, which is UTF-8.

The bytes `0xc0`, `0xc1`, and `0xf5` through `0xff` can appear nowhere in a valid UTF-8 sequence. There are many specifc *sequences* of bytes that also cannot appear in a valid UTF-8 sequence. Some examples of two-byte sequences that cannot appear are `0xxxxxxx 10xxxxxx`, where `x` is any bit. So there's 8,192 to choose from. You can add more `10xxxxxx`'s after that, which also would never appear as a sequence, for more bits.

The least intrusive I think would be to decode the UTF-8 string, insert your tokens only between valid UTF-8 codes, and have those tokens be a sequence of any number of `10xxxxxx` bytes. Then you can encode six bits per inserted byte, and you can easily tell when your token ends, which is the next byte that is not `10xxxxxx`.

So, you could take any one of those single invalid bytes, or all of them, and have each be a prefix to some number of bytes that represent your tokens, inserted anywhere in the data. Or you could use the sequence of `10xxxxxx` bytes between valid codes.